# Finding direction of travel in a world with wrapped edges

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to find the shortest distance direction from one point in my 2D world to another point where the edges are wrapped (like asteroids etc). I know how to find the shortest distance but am struggling  to find which direction it's in.

The shortest distance is given by:

```
int rows = MapY;
int cols = MapX;

int d1 = abs(S.Y - T.Y);
int d2 = abs(S.X - T.X);
int dr = min(d1, rows-d1);
int dc = min(d2, cols-d2);

double dist = sqrt((double)(dr*dr + dc*dc));
```

Example of the world

```
                   :         
                   :  T    
                   :         
    :--------------:---------
    :              :
    :           S  :
    :              :
    :              :
    :  T           :
    :              :
    :--------------:
```

In the diagram the edges are shown with : and -. I've shown a wrapped repeat of the world at the top right too. I want to find the direction in degrees from S to T. So the shortest distance is to the top right repeat of T. but how do I calculate the direction in degreed from S to the repeated T in the top right?

I know the positions of both S and T but I suppose I need to find the position of the repeated T however there more than 1.

The worlds coordinates system starts at 0,0 at the top left and 0 degrees for the direction could start at West.

It seems like this shouldn’t be too hard but I haven’t been able to work out a solution. I hope somone can help? Any websites would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the coordinates for the T in the top right?

Comment: I have never seen a game with diagonal wrapping. Usually you have one wrap for each direction (N,E,S,W).

Comment: Any game that has both horizontal and vertical wrapping has diagonal wrapping by default.

Comment: Think of each coordinate as living on a circle, and figure out the shorter of the two possible distances for each coordinate individually.

Comment: @Kerrek SB That sounds intresting i'll think about it do you have any further info a website etc?

Comment: @Adhemar thats what this question is about trying to find which repeated T is closest and then maybe find it's coords but they will be out side the map.

Comment: @crazy: Look up "torus" on Wikipedia...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to tweak your algorithm a bit to calculate the angle - currently you only record the absolute difference in position, but you need the relative difference (i.e. can be positive or negative depending on positioning).

```
int dx = T.X - S.X; // difference in position
int dy = T.Y - S.Y;

if (dx > MapX / 2) // if distance is bigger than half map width, then looping must be closer
    dx = (dx - MapX) * -1; // reduce distance by map width, reverse 
else if (dx < -MapX / 2) // handle the case that dx is negative
    dx = (dx + MapX) * -1;

//Do the same for dy
if (dy > MapY / 2)
    dy = (dy - MapY) * -1;
else if (dy < -MapY / 2)
    dy = (dy + MapY) * -1;

double dist = sqrt(dy*dy+dx*dx); // same as before
double angle = atan2(dy,dx) * 180 / PI; // provides angle in degrees
```

Comment: You need some work on the signs of dx and dy as the code as is will break if T.X is less than S.X or T.Y is less than X.Y. Other than that this is the best solution IMHO.

Comment: Right then I'll fix that.

Comment: Still got a few errors on what the sign of dx and dy will be when all is said and done, mind if I edit?

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?? **It doesn't even work**. Suppose `MapX` is 100, `T.X` is 90 and `S.X` is 10. `dx` should clearly be 20, but this algorithm will return 30!

Comment: Ugh this is what happens when you don't have to opportunity to test code before posting it. Will fix. If someone finds another error with this I'll probably just delete it before too many people get mislead.

Answer (score 12):

In such a world there are **infinite** number of paths from S to T. Let's denote the coordinates of T by `(Tx, Ty)`, the coordinates of S by `(Sx, Sy)`, and the size of the world by `(Wx, Wy)`. The wrapped coordinates of T are `(Tx + i * Wx, Ty + j * Wy)`, where `i` and `j` are integers, that is, elements of the set `{..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...}`. The vectors connecting S to T are `(Dx, Dy) := (Tx + i * Wx - Sx, Ty + j * Wy - Sy)`. For a given `(i, j)` pair, the distance is the length of the vector, `sqrt(Dx * Dx + Dy * Dy)`, and the direction in radians is `atan(Dy / Dx)`. The **shortest path** is one of the 9 paths, where `i` and `j` are in `{-1, 0, 1}`:
[image]

The `i` and `j` values for the **shortest path** can be determined directly:

```
int i = Sx - Tx > Wx / 2 ? 1 : Sx - Tx < -Wx / 2 ? -1 : 0;
int j = Sy - Ty > Wy / 2 ? 1 : Sy - Ty < -Wy / 2 ? -1 : 0;
```

Thank you, @IlmariKaronen, @SamHocevar and @romkyns for your help!

Comment: You can do better than that: if `abs(Tx-Sx) < Wx/2`, then `i=0` is optimal; otherwise the optimal choice is `i=-1` or `i=1`, depending on the sign of `Tx-Sx`.  Same goes for `Ty-Sy` and `j`.

Comment: This answer is incredibly complicated for such a simple problem. There is no need to use linear search when the minimal value can be calculated directly.

Comment: Nice pic, but the algorithm suggested doesn't deserve any of the upvotes this answer has received.

Answer (score 5):

Compute one possible direction vector, even if it's not the shortest, then wrap its X coordinate so that it is in the `[-MapX/2,MapX/2]` range, and same for Y:

```
int DirX = (T.X - S.X + 3 * MapX / 2) % MapX) - MapX / 2;
int DirY = (T.Y - S.Y + 3 * MapY / 2) % MapY) - MapY / 2;
```

That's it! You also get the distance without further calculations:

```
double dist = sqrt((double)(DirX*DirX + DirY*DirY));
```

Comment: Thanks! GLSL version: `vec2 toroidalNearestWay (vec2 from, vec2 to, vec2 mapSize) { return (mod((to - from + 3.0 * mapSize / 2.0), mapSize)) - mapSize / 2.0; }`

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are a number of ways to do this. Here are 2 I can think of off the top of my head:

**#1: Handle cases manually**

There are exactly 10 cases that can happen:

- It's in the same tile as `S`
- It's in any of the 8 surrounding tiles
- It's not found at all.

For each of the surrounding tiles though, they are permutations of different calculations for the X or Y distance component. Because it's a finite number of cases, you can just hard-code how to calculate them, and find the shortest distance between all of them.

Here's an illustration of 2 cases for finding `dx`. Case 1, where `T` is in the same tile as `S`, dx is just `S.x - T.x`. For the tiles to the right, `dx` will be calculated as `TileWidth - S.x + T.x`.

```
               :         
               :  T    
               :         
:--------------:---------
:              :
:           S  :
:  |--------|--:--|
:dx=(S.x-T.x) dx=(TileWidth-S.x+T.x)
:  T           :
:              :
:--------------:
```

As a small optimization, find the minimum distance before you take a square root. Then you save yourself up to 7 `sqrt` calls.

**#2: Abstract the coordinates**

If you need to do something more spacially "fluid", like a path-finding algorithm, just abstract the coordinates so your path finding algorithm doesn't even realize the world is made of repeating tiles. The path-finding algorithm could go infinitely in any direction theoretically (ok well you'll be limited by numeric limits, but you get the point).

For simple distance calculation, don't bother doing this.

Comment: Smart idea about comparing the squared distance value before taking the sqrt!

Comment: Ah I see, @Kol has a similar answer with a more mathematical explanation, thanks this gives me something to work with

Comment: Comparing the squared distance may be smarter than taking the sqrt, but using the Manhattan distance is even smarter since it requires no multiplication at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with the "9 directions". The reason is that there are 5 degenerate cases amongst those 9: "straight north", "straigt west", "straight south", "straight east" and "identical".
For instance, straight north is degenerate because it represents the case where northwest and northeast join and produce the same result.

Thus, you have 4 directions to calculate, and can just pick the minimum.

Comment: I don't think this is right, or I've completely misunderstood you.  One of the two.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the answers in the end I used Toomai  edited by Scott Chamberlain. I had too make a few changes due to the fact that my coordinate system starts with y at the top left and increases as you move down (basically inverted compared to normal graph coordinates for y).

I've posted in case anyone else finds this page and has the same reversed y system.

```
  int dx = T.X - S.X; // difference in position
int dy = S.Y - T.Y;

if (dx > MapX / 2) // if distance is bigger than half map width, then looping must be closer
    dx = (dx - (MapX / 2)) * -1; // reduce distance by half map width, reverse 
else if (dx < -MapX / 2) // handle the case that dx is negative
    dx = (dx + (MapX / 2)) * -1;

//Do the same for dy
if (dy > MapY / 2)
    dy = (MapY - dy)) * -1;
else if (dy < -MapY / 2)
    dy = (dy + MapY);

double angle = atan2(dy,dx) * 180 / PI; // provides angle in degrees

angle = 180 - angle; //convert to 360 deg
```

Comment: This code is slightly better than Toomai's but doesn't work either.

Comment: Also, you need to understand _why_ you had to do these changes. It's _not_ because your coordinate system starts with `y` at the top. It's because the desired behaviour is supposedly to _wrap_ coordinates at the world edge, whereas the code you reused _mirrored_ the coordinates at each boundary.